# Sending multibyte data via cURL in PHP

Tags: php, api, curl

I'm creating an API for an application I'm writing for a client as they want both a website and a mobile app.  The API and application are written in PHP, using the Codeigniter framework.

I want to upload a file via the application using the input file.  How can I then send this file over cURL to the API so I can get the file in the $_FILES variable?

Ideally, I would like to use POST methods, but I can also use PUT or similar if necessary.

Thanks

S

=== UPDATE ===

I know how to pass the file from the application to the API - the thrust of my question is more to do with how to then parse the file once it's in the API.  If you upload a file using a form, you get a temp file reference in $_FILES - that's what I want to emulate.

Comment: What exactly you want? Is this question about how to access input files from CodeIgniter?

Comment: No.  I'm trying to establish how to establish how to retrieve a file in the API just using the PHP stuff (I can work out how to do it Codeigniter after). If you posted a form, the file would be in $_FILES. This won't be possible in an API so how do I do it?

Comment: As far as I can understand from your words is that CodeIgniter somewhat hides the super global $_FILES and you have no way to access it with your current implementation of the API. I had a glance on the CodeIgniter wiki, they seems to have a module/plug-in that deals with the input files. Is that what you want?

Comment: Possibly. Have you got a link?

Comment: See if this helps. https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Extended-Input-for-Files

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, _VIRUS_SCAN_URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
// same as <input type="file" name="file_box">
$post = array(
    "file_box"=>"@/path/to/myfile.jpg",
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

?>

reference :: http://dtbaker.com.au/random-bits/uploading-a-file-using-curl-in-php.html

Answer (score 0):

Append a '@' character before the file path to upload a file.

In your case, use the tmp_name from the input file.

Assuming the incoming file is send via POST, with the name 'input_file'.

```
$curl = curl_init(/* Your URL goes here. */);

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        'file' => "@$_FILES[input_file][tmp_name]"
    )
));

curl_exec($curl);
```

Hope that helps.